# Plain text in itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize

I want to write something like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item
        \item Want some code \begin{verbatim}
          \pause
        \end{verbatim}
       Done with it
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

But it fails with this error!

```
Runaway argument?
 \pause \end {verbatim}
```

What's going on and how to write verbatim in itemize environment?

Comment: you need `[fragile]` argument to `frame` to have any verbatim  material in a frame

Comment: Now it says: "Missing $ inserted" for the first item

Comment: sorry but if you want someone to debug an error message you need to post a complete small document that generates the error,

Comment: Solved it putting "[fragile]" AFTER {frame}, not before, as I've done firstly